# Is it possible to have multiple xml layout files for the same activity in android?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am developing an app that has a viewpager, the problem is that it's components looses its's position when I try to fix it on particular screen size,it gets disturbed for another screen size.So I want to ask is it possible to have separate multiple layout files for the same activity for different screen sizes,if yes please tell me the procedure to do it.
Seeking for help,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, you can do it programmatically, checking the screen size and all the specs you want, but honestly I would like to suggest you instead to work properly on the layout, you can have a responsive, adaptable and resizeable layout if you follow the recommendations from google.

I highly suggest you to take a look at this article : https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes, or https://www.raywenderlich.com/155838/responsive-ui-tutorial-android , there are a lot more tutorials on the internet, if you learn how to play right with the layouts and its constraints you can create a single layout for several devices and its screens, that's the actual purpose of the Android layouts.